# Append CSS in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to append different colors to some text:

```
var s = ["red", "green"];   
for (i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
    $(".colors").append("<span>TEXT </span>").css("color", s[i]);
}
```

The output of both spans is green, but my intention was that the first one is going to be red and only the second one green. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

That's because `append` returns the selected element not the appended element, so you are modifying color of the `.colors` element(s) not the appended elements, the last color wins and descendant elements inherit the color property.

```
$("<span>TEXT</span>").css("color", s[i]).appendTo(".colors");
```